# Disable user name from navigation link in active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How do I hide or disable the current username with the show page link from the navigation bar in activeadmin gem?

**ruby 2.6.3**

**rails 5.2.3**

**config/initializers**

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.site_title = "Myapp"
  config.footer = "MYapp"
  config.root_to = 'admin/users#index'
  config.logout_link_path = :logout_path
  config.logout_link_method = :delete
  config.current_user_method = :current_user
  config.comments = false
  config.batch_actions = false
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
     admin.build_menu do |menu|
         menu.add :label => "My Custom Link", :url => "/", :priority => 0
         menu.add :label => "Pages" do |pages|
         pages.add :label => "Homepage", :url => "/admin/homepage"
         pages.add :label => "About Us", :url => "/admin/about-us"
         pages.add :label => "Facebook", :url => "http://www.facebook.com", :html_options => { :target => "_blank" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for [overriding the utility menu](https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#utility-navigation):

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.build_menu :utility_navigation do |menu|
      admin.add_logout_button_to_menu menu
    end
  end
end
```